# How to join 3 tables with different data between them?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, pdo

I'm not too good with explaining things, apologies.

I have 3 tables that are similar to the below:

```
users
    id
    username
threads
    id
    title
    user_id
    lastpost_id
posts
    id
    content
    thread_id
    user_id
```

On a page listing forum threads, I want the username of both the thread author, and the last post author of that thread to be displayed, I'm attempting to achieve this in a single query.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT t.*,u.username FROM threads t
INNER JOIN users u ON t.user_id=u.id
INNER JOIN posts p ON t.lastpost_id=p.id
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

The first join enables me to get the username of the user id that started the thread.

The second join is what I'm not sure on, it can get me the user id but how do I get the username from that, as a 3rd join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the same table multiple times if you give it a different alias. You can give the fields aliases too:

```
SELECT 
  t.*,
  tu.username as threadusername, /* Result field is called 'threadusername' */
  p.*,
  pu.username as lastpostusername 
FROM threads t
INNER JOIN users tu ON t.user_id=tu.id /* thread user */
INNER JOIN posts p ON t.lastpost_id=p.id
INNER JOIN users pu ON p.user_id=pu.id /* post user */
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join to a joined table like this:

```
SELECT t.*,u.username,u2.username FROM threads t
INNER JOIN users u ON t.user_id=u.id
INNER JOIN posts p ON t.lastpost_id=p.id
INNER JOIN users u2 ON p.user_id=u2.id
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

Note, I haven't had time to test it, but it should work (at least in MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got it correctly, but as per my understanding you can have a inner query to fetch the thread ids and then have a outer query to fetch the posts based on the thread id, have a max on post id and group by user id. Also join to user to have the name. Hope that helps.